# Search filter on list view returns wrong result on clicking

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

**Problem**
I am creating music player using android studio.
Everything was fine until I added search filter to search songs.
Search filter returns the song right but when I click on searched result wrong music file is opened however the music name shown on player activity is right but the song played is first song of list every time .
**Example**
There are 4 song items named: A,B,C,D
When searched C ,filtered result C is shown. But when Clicked on it Song name C is shown but Song A is played.

This is really frustrating.

*Main Activity.java*

```
package com.example.musicplayer2;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.icu.text.Transliterator;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SearchEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static boolean shuffleBol = false;
    static boolean loopBol = false;


    ListView listView;
    String[] items;
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listViewSong);
        runtimePermission();

    }


    public void runtimePermission()
    {

        Dexter.withContext(this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                        displaySongs();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {

                        permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();

    }


    public ArrayList<File> findSong(File file)
    {
        ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        if (files != null){

            for (File singlefile : files)
            {
                if (singlefile.isDirectory() && !singlefile.isHidden())
                {
                    arrayList.addAll(findSong(singlefile));
                }

                else
                {
                    if (singlefile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") && !singlefile.getName().startsWith("."))
                    {
                        arrayList.add(singlefile);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return arrayList;
    }



    void displaySongs()
    {
        ArrayList<File> mysongs;
        mysongs = findSong(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

        items = new String[mysongs.size()];

        for (int i=0; i < mysongs.size(); i++)
        {
            items[i] = mysongs.get(i).getName().replace(".mp3","");

        }

//        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;
        myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String songName = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PlayerActivity.class)
                .putExtra("songs",mysongs)
                .putExtra("songname",songName)
                .putExtra("position",position));
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);

        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_view);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                myAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



}
```

*main activity.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewSong"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

*PlayerActivity.java*

```
package com.example.musicplayer2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import static com.example.musicplayer2.MainActivity.loopBol;
import static com.example.musicplayer2.MainActivity.shuffleBol;

public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView btnplay,btnnext,btnprev,btnshuffle,btnloop;
    TextView txtsname,txtstart,txtstop;
    SeekBar seekmusic;

    String sname;

    public static final String EXTRA_NAME = "song_name";
    static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    int position;
    ArrayList<File> mySongs;

    Thread updateseekbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Player");


        btnprev = findViewById(R.id.btnprev);
        btnnext = findViewById(R.id.btnnext);
        btnplay = findViewById(R.id.playbtn);
        btnshuffle = findViewById(R.id.btnshuffle);
        btnloop = findViewById(R.id.btnloop);


        txtsname = findViewById(R.id.txtsn);
        txtstart = findViewById(R.id.txtstart);
        txtstop = findViewById(R.id.txtstop);

        seekmusic = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);




//        if a media player is already running then.
        if (mediaPlayer != null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }

        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();

        mySongs = (ArrayList)bundle.getParcelableArrayList("songs");
        String songName = i.getStringExtra("songname");
        position = bundle.getInt("position",0);
        txtsname.setSelected(true);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
        sname = mySongs.get(position).getName();
        txtsname.setText(sname);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),uri);
        mediaPlayer.start();

        updateseekbar = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                int currentPosition = 0;
                while (currentPosition<totalDuration)
                {
                    try {
                        sleep(500);
                        currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                        seekmusic.setProgress(currentPosition);
                    }

                    catch (InterruptedException | IllegalStateException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        seekmusic.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        updateseekbar.start();

        seekmusic.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                mediaPlayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
            }
        });

        String endTime = createTime(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        txtstop.setText(endTime);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final int delay = 1000;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String currentTime = createTime(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                txtstart.setText(currentTime);
                handler.postDelayed(this,delay);
            }
        },delay);

        //        click Listener ON PLAY button

        btnplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                {
                    btnplay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                }

                else
                {
                    btnplay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }
        });

        //        click Listener ON next button

        btnnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();

                if (shuffleBol && !loopBol){
                    position=getRandom((mySongs.size()));
                }

                else if(!shuffleBol && !loopBol)
                {
                    position=((position+1)%mySongs.size());
                }

                Uri u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);
                sname=mySongs.get(position).getName();
                txtsname.setText(sname);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                btnplay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                String endTime = createTime(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                txtstop.setText(endTime);

            }
        });


        //        click Listener ON previous button

        btnprev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();



                if (shuffleBol && !loopBol){
                    position=getRandom((mySongs.size()));
                }

                else if(!shuffleBol && !loopBol){
                        position=((position-1)<0)?(mySongs.size()-1):(position-1);
                }

                Uri u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);
                sname=mySongs.get(position).getName();
                txtsname.setText(sname);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                btnplay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                String endTime = createTime(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                txtstop.setText(endTime);
            }
        });

        //        click listener for shuffle btn

        btnshuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (shuffleBol){
                    shuffleBol=false;
                    btnshuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.shuffle_off);
                }

                else {
                    shuffleBol=true;
                    btnshuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.shuffle_on);
                }

            }
        });

        //        click listener for loop btn

        btnloop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (loopBol){
                    loopBol=false;
                    btnloop.setImageResource(R.drawable.loop_off);
                }

                else {
                    loopBol=true;
                    btnloop.setImageResource(R.drawable.loop_on);
                }
            }
        });



//        next Listener ON song completion

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                btnnext.performClick();
            }
        });






    }


    public String createTime(int duration)
    {
        String time = "";
        int min = duration/1000/60;
        int sec = duration/1000%60;

        time+=min+":";

        if (sec<10)
        {
            time+="0";
        }
        time+=sec;

        return time;
    }

    private int getRandom(int i) {
        Random random= new Random();
        return random.nextInt(i+1);
    }

}
```

*PlayerActivity.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context=".PlayerActivity"
    android:baselineAligned="false">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp,UselessParent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtsn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"

            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/song_name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="italic">

        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo">

        </ImageView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp">

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekbar"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">

            </SeekBar>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtstart"
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-17dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/seekbar"
                android:text="0:00"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtstop"
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-14dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seekbar"
                android:text="@string/_4_10"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp">

            </TextView>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="98dp"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/playbtn"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/pause" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnnext"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playbtn"
                android:background="@drawable/next" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnprev"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/playbtn"
                android:background="@drawable/previous" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnshuffle"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnprev"
                android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shuffle_off"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnloop"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnnext"
                android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/loop_off"/>





        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you need to provide `PlayerActivity`! To see what happens on it.

Comment: I just did. @MajidHajibaba

Comment: @AbhishekSemwal. looks like the issue is that you are sending the position of filter array and sending the songs list which is not filtered. That's why it's happening. 

So you need to do is that either send the filtered array. Or add some logic to get the correct position from songs list. 

that's it.

Comment: Please provide the appropriate logic

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In above image, you see that you are sending the position of filtered array and sending the songs list (mysongs) which is not filtered. That's why it's happening.

So you need to do is that either send the filtered array. Or add some logic to get the correct position from songs list. that's it.

if you can not figure out then let me know I will update appropriate logic.

Comment: On next page I need playing  filtered song.